# filter list of dictionary based on two values

Tags: python

I have dictionary:

`[{"score":-10, "name": "Tom", "etc": 1}, {"score":-20, "name": "Tom", "etc": 2} {"score":-110, "name": "Jerry", "etc": 3}, {"score":-210, "name": "Jerry",, "etc": 5}]`

How can I filter list so that I have only one `unique` name with lowest score.

Desired result:

`[ {"score":-20, "name": "Tom", "etc": 2}, {"score":-210, "name": "Jerry",, "etc": 5}]`

How can accomplish that easily, wit build in libraries, whiteout using something like pandas?

Comment: "whiteout using something like pandas": the thing is, especially when your list is a bit bigger than this example, Pandas is basically the tool to use for this kind of thing. So I'm curious why you not want to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you currently have isn't a dict, but a list of dicts.  Turning this into a dict of dicts (keyed on name) makes it easy to ensure that each name is unique:

```
>>> data = [{"score":-10, "name": "Tom", "etc": 1}, {"score":-20, "name": "Tom", "etc": 2}, {"score":-110, "name": "Jerry", "etc": 3}, {"score":-210, "name": "Jerry", "etc": 5}]
>>> data_by_name = {}
>>> for d in data:
...     name = d["name"]
...     if name not in data_by_name or data_by_name[name]["score"] > d["score"]:
...         data_by_name[name] = d
...
>>> data_by_name
{'Tom': {'score': -20, 'name': 'Tom', 'etc': 2}, 'Jerry': {'score': -210, 'name': 'Jerry', 'etc': 5}}
>>> list(data_by_name.values())
[{'score': -20, 'name': 'Tom', 'etc': 2}, {'score': -210, 'name': 'Jerry', 'etc': 5}]
```

You can also do this in one line with a fancy list comprehension -- note that the below example is less efficient than the first example because it iterates over the entire list multiple times:

```
>>> [min((d for d in data if d["name"] == name), key=lambda d: d["score"]) for name in {d["name"] for d in data}]
[{'score': -20, 'name': 'Tom', 'etc': 2}, {'score': -210, 'name': 'Jerry', 'etc': 5}]
```